# Load-Testing a Java-Client-Server-Application

Tags: java, spring-remoting, performance-testing

we use spring-remoting for a Client-Server-Application. Now we are in doubt how to realize a real load test with serialized objects.

The problem is that many load testing toolkits are based on plain text HTTP communication, so it's very easy to parameterize the http-requests. Because spring-remoting is based on serialized objects we can't easily parameterize the http-communication to the server.

My first idea was to encapsulate the endpoint of spring-remoting and to call the service over client-side service classes. But how can I realize calling the remote-service from multiply clients to gain a real load test scenario?
Are there any solution for wrapping the client-side service in an easy manner?

Has anybody some experiences how to realize it?

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 1):

There is a discussion on the [Spring forums](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=12477) about how to use JMeter to do testing. To use JMeter you'll need to write a custom Sampler. They have examples on the [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) site.

Alternatively, you could try [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/). Testing scripts are written using jython but it is arguably easier to create tests for non-standard protocols.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [commercial](https://ubikloadpack.com) JMeter plugin which allows this, see:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/load-testing-java-serialization-applications-with-jmeter/

To make your tests realistic, you will need to variabilize content in the
serialized objects.

This Java Serialization plugin will allow the following:

- Easy recording of traffic with JMeter Proxy Server, a Test Plan using
  custom Sampler will be created
- Easy variabilization of requests (which will appear as XML) through as
  easy syntax as for example ${searchedWord} where searchedWord can come from
  a CSV or any user defined variable.
- Easy extraction of data from responses using JMeter standard Post
  Processors
- Easy debugging of Request/Responses through standard JMeter View Results
  Tree element

Disclaimer : I am member of the company that distributes this solution